# How to fetch messages from a lync conversation using powershell?

Tags: powershell, automation, lync

I researched a bit and found a way to leverage Lync 2013 SDK to send an IM to a contact in my contact list. But it would be much more useful if there were a way to get messages from the conversation window.

Comment: Can you add what you research, what is wrong and the desired output is? Have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/csps/2011/05/05/send-an-instant-message-from-a-script/)
I used this as a guide to write a small script to send messages through lync.

Answer (score 0):

See [Sample send receive Lync / Skype for business messages using powershell](https://psvmware.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/sample-send-receive-lync-skype-for-business-messages-using-powershell/) (Author: Grzegorz Kulikowski)

**to test with another user**

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\lyncsdk\Assemblies\Desktop"
Import-Module .\Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll
$Client = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()
$Conversation = $client.ConversationManager.AddConversation()
$person=$client.ContactManager.GetContactByUri('person@domain.com')
$conversation.AddParticipant($person)


Get-EventSubscriber|Unregister-Event
# For each participant in the conversation

$conversation.Participants | Where { !$_.IsSelf } | foreach {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $_.Modalities[1] -EventName "InstantMessageReceived" -SourceIdentifier "person $i" -action { 
    $global:conv = $event
    $msg = $conv.SourceEventArgs.Text.trim()
    write-host $msg
    switch -Wildcard ($msg) {
     "What*" {$Conversation.Modalities['InstantMessage'].BeginSendMessage((Invoke-Expression $msg.split()[-1]), {}, 0)}
     "Hello" {$Conversation.Modalities['InstantMessage'].BeginSendMessage("Hello human", {}, 0)}
     "stupid robot" {$Conversation.Modalities['InstantMessage'].BeginSendMessage("Humanity is overrated", {}, 0)}
    }
    }
    $i++
   }
```

**to test with yourself**

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\lyncsdk\Assemblies\Desktop"
Import-Module .\Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll
$Client = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()
$Conversation = $client.ConversationManager.AddConversation()
$conversation.AddParticipant($client.Self.Contact)

Get-EventSubscriber|Unregister-Event
  $conversation.Participants[0]| foreach {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $_.Modalities[1] -EventName "InstantMessageReceived" -SourceIdentifier "person $i" -action { 
    $global:conv = $event
    $msg = $conv.SourceEventArgs.Text.trim()
    write-host $msg
    #if ($msg -like 'What*') {$Conversation.Modalities['InstantMessage'].BeginSendMessage((Invoke-Expression $msg.split()[-1]), {}, 0)}
    switch -Wildcard ($msg) {
     "What*" {$Conversation.Modalities['InstantMessage'].BeginSendMessage((Invoke-Expression $msg.split()[-1]), {}, 0)}
     "Hello" {$Conversation.Modalities['InstantMessage'].BeginSendMessage("Hello human", {}, 0)}
     "stupid robot" {$Conversation.Modalities['InstantMessage'].BeginSendMessage("Humanity is overrated", {}, 0)}
    }
    }
    $i++
   }
```

Also, these may help:

[Send and receive text in a conversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/sendreceivetext)

[Learn Skype Web SDK Day 15 : Receiving Instant Messages](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/05/learn-skype-web-sdk-day-15-receiving-instant-messages/)

Comment: I am getting this error when tried this script:

`format-default : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Co 
   mmands.FormatDefaultCommand`

Comment: @KarthicSrinivasan  Did you install the Lync SDK package as described in the link at the top of my answer? [Sample send receive Lync / Skype for business messages using powershell](https://psvmware.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/sample-send-receive-lync-skype-for-business-messages-using-powershell/)? It says: "Before you start you need to obtain the Lync SDK package: [lyncsdk.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/6/056013D5-98F8-4B79-88EF-D221E519C37F/lyncsdk.exe)

Comment: yes i have installed the lynk sdk. still getting the error. This line `$conversation.AddParticipant($person)` is trowing this exception

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the details of your setup, i.e., OS, PowerShell version, what account you're using, etc., etc. A search on the exception text revealed this: [Exception has been thrown while reading SSA via PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/dee26f6a-bded-4fd9-ab63-543fb72095a7/exception-has-been-thrown-while-reading-ssa-via-powershell?forum=sharepointadminprevious). Good luck!